# I think I cannot extend PHP Class properly

Tags: php, extends

guys! I am practising class extending now but I think I really miss something.

I have some variables first:

```
$username = "antonradev";
$name = "Anton Radev";
$email = "antonradev@example.com";
$profession = "Designer";
$job_title = "Web Design Manager";
$job_location = "Sofia";
```

My parent class:

```
class User {
    public $username;
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function __construct($username, $name, $email) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

}
```

After this I extend like this:

```
class User_Professional extends User {

    public $user_profession;
    public $user_job_title;
    public $user_work_location;

    public function __construct($user_profession, $user_job_title, $user_work_location) {
        $this->user_profession = $user_profession;
        $this->user_job_title = $user_job_title;
        $this->user_work_location = $user_work_location;
    }

}
```

I create an instance:

```
$user_professional = new User_Professional($username, $name, $email, $profession, $job_title, $job_location);
```

And I am trying to print some data:

```
print "The employee username is: " . $user_professional->username;
```

But nothing happen. Its empty with no errors:

*The employee username is:*

Then I make some changes and I am trying to print other property:

```
print "The employee`s job title is: " . $user_professional->user_job_title;
```

But I get data from the parent class. It prints wrong property:

*The employee`s job title is: Anton Radev*

Is this normal? Where is my mistake? I cannot handle it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You must call the constructor of `User` class and pass 3 arguments there `$username, $name, $email`.

`User` class constructor:

```
public function __construct($username, $name, $email) {
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->email = $email;
}
```

`User_Professional` class constructor:

```
public function __construct($username, $name, $email, $user_profession, $user_job_title, $user_work_location) {
    parent::__construct($username, $name, $email);

    $this->user_profession = $user_profession;
    $this->user_job_title = $user_job_title;
    $this->user_work_location = $user_work_location;
}
```

Comment: Oh! I did not know this.. Do I have to include with this parent:: in every extended class the initial parent functions? Is this valid only for the constructors? Thank you!

Comment: Usually you should always call `parent::__construct()` in child classes constructors. However, parent's constructor is automatically called if you DO NOT explicitly define constructor in your child class. More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php Also, dont forget mark my answer as accepted, if you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class User_Professional extends User {

    public $user_profession;
    public $user_job_title;
    public $user_work_location;

    public function __construct($user_profession, $user_job_title, $user_work_location) {

        // Need to pass the usename, name, email
        parent::__construct($username, $name, $email);

        $this->user_profession = $user_profession;
        $this->user_job_title = $user_job_title;
        $this->user_work_location = $user_work_location;
    }

}
```

### Alternate

```
class User {
    public $username;
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->username = "antonradev";
        $this->name = "Anton Radev";
        $this->email = "antonradev@example.com";
    }

}
```

And use in your child class like

```
class User_Professional extends User {

    public $user_profession;
    public $user_job_title;
    public $user_work_location;

    public function __construct($user_profession, $user_job_title, $user_work_location) {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->user_profession = $user_profession;
        $this->user_job_title = $user_job_title;
        $this->user_work_location = $user_work_location;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I added this line (parent::__construct($username, $name, $email);) and I get three errors about "Notice: Undefined variable..."

Comment: @AntonRadev this is because you have to pass the `$username, $name, $email` to the `parent::__construct($username, $name, $email)` to initiate your parent class

Comment: Yes. Now my child class constructor is public function __construct($username, $name, $email, $user_profession, $user_job_title, $user_work_location). It seems lot of properties adding all the time everywhere. :( What is the use of the extending then. I dont get it again..

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your parents constructor. You need to call it.

```
class User_Professional extends User {

  public $user_profession;
  public $user_job_title;
  public $user_work_location;

  public function __construct($user_profession, $user_job_title, $user_work_location) {
    parent::__constructor($username, $name, $email);

    $this->user_profession = $user_profession;
    $this->user_job_title = $user_job_title;
    $this->user_work_location = $user_work_location;
  }
}
```

Comment: Overriding, not overwriting.

Comment: Hm.. It seems like double job. I have to include every time the parent properties and methods. But what If I do not know them? I thought inheritance is a way of working with child class without thinking about the parent one. I have gotten the ideas wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) or [mixin](http://php.net/traits) instead of inheritance in this case.

Comment: Hi, Ostrovski! Thank you! I am not that far in the book :) And I think it is not mentioned as a topic. What is the different in this case? Isn`t inheritance the way to give a child class the initial properties of the parent one and the child class gets more properties we can use?

Comment: You are right ofcourse and my answer is just a little offtopic. But when you will need another one User* class like User_Father and then another one like User_Politician you will make all available combination of such classes (i.e. User_ProfessionalAndPolititian, User_FaterAndPolititian) to obtain all desired properties in some place in code. Such combinatoric growth of new classes can be avoided with composition or mixin technics.